# Distributions with negative support in JAGS

Tags: regression, distributions, bayesian, prior, jags

I am creating a Bayesian regression model where I want to include a prior for a variable that can only have a negative coefficient. What distribution can I use that only has a negative support and is compatible with jags?

Comment: You have a cornucopia of solutions ready at hand. The negative of a variable with positive support obviously will do.  *Every* distribution with negative support can be expressed in this form.  The negative of the absolute value of a variable also works; and again, *every* distribution with negative support can be expressed in this form.  The negative of the square of a variable works or, more generally, the negative of any positive function of any variable works.  *Every* distribution of negative support can also be expressed in such a form.

Answer (score 1):

- You could take negatively-valued $X$ and transform it into $Y = -X$, so that you could use a distribution with positive-only support for $Y$.
- You could any distribution with no such restriction, for example Gaussian, and truncate it from above at zero.
- There are [many probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) and you can even come up with your own. It is an impossible task to list them all. You should probably ask yourself what are the other requirements from the distribution besides the support, since many of the distributions would meet the requirement of the negative support, or can be transformed to such using the methods like above.